# Scala: How to implement the following without using var

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and not able to get the better way to do a thing without if and else statement. As immutability is the way to go in scala and its not recommended to use var, how will we implement the following without using var

```
var requests = callFunc1()
if requests.isEmpty requests = callFunc2()

def callFunc1(): List[Int]
def callFunc2(): List[Int]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use additional container filtering it, and use getOrElse:

```
val requests = Option(func1()).filter(_.nonEmpty).getOrElse(func2())
```

Comment: What I like about this answer is that it lifts whether or not the list is valid into a datatype other than the direct representation - `func1` is a possibly invalid return value, `Some(func1).filter(_.nonEmpty)` is either an invalid result `None`, or a valid result `Some(validlist)`

Answer (score 8):

Going the the requirements you list, and the semantics you show in the example (e.g. evaluate `callFunc1` once, evaluate `callFunc2` once if and only if `callFunc1` evaluates to `Nil`) The following meets your requirements.

```
val requests = callFunc1 match {
  case Nil => callFunc2
  case nonempty => nonempty
}
```

However, I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with using `if` and a temporary value either.

```
val requests = {
  val f1 = callFunc1
  if (f1.isEmpty) callFunc2 else f1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Martijn is very good if the functions definitions are fixed. An alternative is to change the signature of `callFunc1` so that it returns `Option[List[Int]]` and then use

```
val requests = callFunc1().getOrElse(callFunc2())

def callFunc1(): Option[List[Int]]
def callFunc2(): List[Int]
```

The advantage of returning an `Option` is that you can distinguish between "I failed to read the list" (`None`) and "I read the list but it was empty" (`Some(List())`).

The choice will depend on the wider structure of the program, and it depends on what `getFunc1` is actually doing and why it might return an empty `List`. For example, if the data comes from a `Map` or a `File` operation, it probably comes wrapped in an `Option` anyway so returning the `Option` might simplify that code as well.

Note that you can convert a `List` to `Option[List]` like this:

```
Option(list).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

This will return `None` if `list` is empty or `null`, otherwise it will return `Some(list)`.